# Typescript - Changes on variable are being reflected on another variable

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have this small piece of code:

```
this.videosProvider.getVideos().subscribe(videos => {
    this.videos = videos;
    this.videosAux = videos;
    console.log(this.videosAux[0].videos)
});
```

What the variable `videos` from the subscribe returns is:

```
[
{
    "categoria": "Tus dudas de salud",
    "videos": [
        {
            "id": "oiVn4NUJo_k",
            "titulo": "La fiebre: mitos y verdades",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/oiVn4NUJo_k",
            "miniatura": "https://img.youtube.com/vi/oiVn4NUJo_k/mqdefault.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "1l_tbEZwBjs",
            "titulo": "¿Por qué estornuda un recién nacido?",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1l_tbEZwBjs",
            "miniatura": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/1l_tbEZwBjs/mqdefault.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Like the way the first code is right now, it prints the videos properly. But if I do:

```
    this.videosProvider.getVideos().subscribe(videos => {
        this.videos = videos;
        this.videos[0].videos = [];
        this.videosAux = videos;
        console.log(this.videosAux[0].videos)
    });
```

It prints an empty array. Also if I print `videos` the same happens. Why is this? I'm changing the value on `this.videos` not `this.videosAux`. The only thing I can think of is that it's somehow related by reference, but I don't understand why or how to fix it.

Can you give me a hand on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because arrays and objects are passing through reference and not as a copy like strings, numbers, booleans do. You need to copy an array to a new independent one. Because you have array of objects, you can use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(videos)).

```
this.videosProvider.getVideos().subscribe(videos => {
    this.videos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(videos));
    this.videos[0].videos = [];
    this.videosAux = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(videos));
    console.log(this.videosAux[0].videos)
});
```

Example for testing:

```js
let someArray = [
{
    "categoria": "Tus dudas de salud",
    "videos": [
        {
            "id": "oiVn4NUJo_k",
            "titulo": "La fiebre: mitos y verdades",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/oiVn4NUJo_k",
            "miniatura": "https://img.youtube.com/vi/oiVn4NUJo_k/mqdefault.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "1l_tbEZwBjs",
            "titulo": "¿Por qué estornuda un recién nacido?",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1l_tbEZwBjs",
            "miniatura": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/1l_tbEZwBjs/mqdefault.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
];

const otherArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someArray));
someArray[0].videos = [];
console.log(otherArray);
```

Comment: Tried that aswell but gives me error: ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Comment: It should work now, Your array is array of objects, so also the objects needs to be cloned. I have updated the answer and provided a test example.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Also I tried to construct the array before returning in on the subscribe. On the way it was before I just returned what was into the JSON. By constructing the array myself it also works now tih .slice()

Thank you very much!

Comment: This solution is not optimal and requires turning the entire JSON to string than parsing it back to JSON. Using slice is a better approach.

Comment: I agree, but if you have array of objects, you have to clone also the objects and slice clones only the array, which leaves the references to the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you want to get a copy of the array into your different variable, you can do

this.videos = videos.slice();

this.videosAux = videos.slice()

without any parameter.